# Make Interfaces Easy to Use Correctly and Hard to Use Incorrectly - Example

Tags: oop, design-patterns, interface, architecture

I was reading best practices for developers and found one suggestion is,

> Make Interfaces Easy to Use Correctly and Hard to Use Incorrectly

Can anyone describe with minimal sample code to understand the principle. I have tried to search on the internet but did not find any example.

```
class Account{
    void process(){}
}

interface IBankAccountService {

    boolean check(Account acc);
    void process(Account acc);
}

class ScbAccountService implements IBankAccountService {

    @Override
    public boolean check(Account acc) {
        return true; // check account consistency
    }

    @Override
    public void process(Account acc) {
        acc.process(); // proceed operation
    }
}
```

Is that above example violating the principle? I so how can I apply this principle in this example.

Comment: Please provide a reference to the source you were reading.

Comment: https://github.com/97-things/97-things-every-programmer-should-know/tree/master/en/thing_55 @jaco0646

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer: you can't do that easily. You have to make the different types in the system depend in one way or the other. In my first example I use an exception in the `perform` methdod's signature to indicate something terrible could happen, if `perform` gets called. This needs to be implemented.

```java
interface Account {

    double getBalance();

    /**
     * Indicates if an order can be performed by the account.
     *
     * @retrun {@code true} if the balance is bigger than the order's amount, {@code false} else.
     */
    boolean canPerform(Order order);

    /**
     * @param order The order to apply.
     * @throws Exception when the amount of the order is higher than the value returned by #getBalance.
     */
    boolean perform(Order order) throws Exception;
}

interface Order { double getAmount(); }

interface Transaction { boolean transact(Account account, Order order) }
```

A different way to model the dependencies, avoiding the exception and (hopefully) produce new `Transaction` instances when `perform` gets called:

```java
interface Account {

    double getBalance();

    /**
     * @param order The order to apply.
     * @throws Exception when the amount of the order is higher than the value returned by #getBalance.
     */
    Transaction perform(Order order);
}

interface Order { double getAmount(); }

interface Transaction { TransactionState getState(); }

enum TransactionState { SUCCESS, ERROR }
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot. So one way is to rather throwing exceptions interface can explicitly return the status so that user can be guided for proper steps. Except that way is there any other scenarios where we can make the interface difficult to use incorrectly.